# User isn't registered

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I am trying to build an app using Kotlin. The user isn't registered in the firebase. I am new to Kotlin. I can't figure out the problem. Here is the code. In the code, all the toast functions work. It shows the toast when those entering fields are empty. But it does not registers the user. Don't know why. Where is the problem? Please help.

```
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.ImageButton
import com.google.firebase.auth.ktx.actionCodeSettings
import android.text.TextUtils
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser




class register_page : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_page)

    val sign_up_button = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.sign_up_btn)
    val sign_up_name = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.sign_up_name)
    val sign_up_email = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.sign_up_email)
    val sign_up_password = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.sign_up_password)

    sign_up_button.setOnClickListener {
        when {
            TextUtils.isEmpty(sign_up_name.text.toString().trim { it <= ' ' }) -> {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this@register_page,
                    "Please enter a name.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }


            TextUtils.isEmpty(sign_up_email.text.toString().trim { it <= ' ' }) -> {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this@register_page,
                    "Please enter an email.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }


            TextUtils.isEmpty(sign_up_password.text.toString().trim { it <= ' ' }) -> {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this@register_page,
                    "Please enter a password.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }


            else -> {
                val email: String = sign_up_email.text.toString().trim { it <= ' ' }
                val password: String = sign_up_password.text.toString().trim { it <= ' ' }
                val user_name: String = sign_up_name.text.toString().trim { it <= ' ' }

                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(
                        OnCompleteListener<AuthResult> { task ->

                            //If registration is successfully done
                            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                                val firebaseUser = task.result!!.user!!

                                Toast.makeText(
                                    this@register_page,
                                    "Registration successful.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                                ).show()


                                val intent =
                                    Intent(this@register_page, MainActivity::class.java)
                                intent.flags =
                                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                                intent.putExtra("user_id", firebaseUser.uid)
                                intent.putExtra("email_id", firebaseUser.email)
                                startActivity(intent)
                                finish()
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(
                                    this@register_page,
                                    task.exception!!.message.toString(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                                ).show()
                            }
                        }
                    )
            }

        }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Does `task.exception!!.message.toString()` display something?

Comment: nope. I does not show anything.

Comment: Sorry for your time everyone.  In the google_services.json file, I have entered an wrong package name by a mistake. It is Engilsh I entered for English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always make sure that the package name is the same.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).